# Should I Exposing Events & How To Properly Event Tracking Firebase w/ Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, firebase, android-jetpack-compose, firebase-analytics

I'm using Compose nowadays. After not long but enough time diving in, I have some questions:

- (1) About the Unidirectional Architecture, I always try my best to follow the pattern by using StateFlow. But I can't figured out when should I openly exposed the state&event, making it modular, or totally closing it with the ViewModel.
- My mentor said that we won't do either. He finds the getting data part is acceptable to be done secretly inside component, and he will always exposes the event. After a while of thinking, I pleasure with the answer, as with accurate naming convention, I can understand what data is the component is working on. On the other hand, events must be exposed, so that we can centralize in one place, it is more convenient for managing. Until recently, when I have a task to attaching Firebase Event tracking.

```
// A small demonstration of my current approach:

@Composable
fun LoginForm(
    onUsernameChange: (String) -> Unit,
    onPasswordChange: (String) -> Unit,
) { 
    val viewModel: FormViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    val uiState by viewModel.uiState.collectAsState()
    ...
}
```

- (2) Without Firebase Tracking, my callback can as simple as `viewModel::setUserName`. But no, now with each event, i have to wrap with an arrow function and add an additional Firebase on top.

```
var firebaseUsernameTyped = remember { false }
...
LoginForm(onUsernameChange = {
    viewModel.setUserName(it)
    if (!firebaseUsernameTyped) {
        Firebase.analytics.logEvent("....", null)
        firebaseUsernameTyped = true
    }
},
    ...
)
```

- My top most Screen Component now be come so large and unable to read.
- More context: I prefer a balancing of nice code convention and productive way, since I don't want to always be perfectionism to my code. I'm using Compose things from scratch, and I not yet seen many instructions for these.

Thanks guys!!!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What's wrong with this approach? Since you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-email-and-password-in-jetpack-compose-bd70ca56ea91) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithEmailAndPassword).

Comment: Thanks but the resource doesn't give me much clue. TLDR, my question is my current approach (closed state & exposed event) doesn't look clean with Firebase Logging Event. Do you have any better approach ?